# Chef-solo create cron based on node.name

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

At the moment I need to install staggered crons based on hostname for recipe that installs clamac. I have a small example that works well however my end product will need to work on nearly hundreds of different hostnames mainly with ascending numbers. Server example: myserver-db[1-12], anotherserver-acc[1-9].

```
cron 'clam-scan-weekly Staggered 1' do
        only_if {node.name == 'myserver-db1' || 'myserver-db3'  }
        minute 30
        hour 22
        weekday 1
        command '/usr/bin/clamscan --exclude-dir="/dev/|/proc/|/run/|/sys/" -l clamscan.log -r /'
        user    'root'
end

cron 'clam-scan-weekly Staggered 2' do
        only_if {node.name == 'myserver-db2' || 'myserver-db4'  }
        minute 30
        hour 22
        weekday 1
        command '/usr/bin/clamscan --exclude-dir="/dev/|/proc/|/run/|/sys/" -l clamscan.log -r /'
        user    'root'
end
```

The end goal is to create three of four staggered cron jobs based on hostnames. I looked into ruby_blocks and it might be do-able however there must be a easier way perhaps. I was hoping that globbing would work but it doesnt...Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you want to stagger the minute or the hour of execution?  How frequently should they run?

Answer (score 0):

So the underlying issue is that `x == 'a' || 'b'` is what you wrote but `x == 'a' || x == 'b'` is what you meant, those are very different.

To solve this without a bajillion lines of copy-paste though:

```
cron 'whatever' do
  # Other properties here.
  minute node.name.hash % 60
end
```